# Maximum number of pythagorean triples on a circle not centered on the origin

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, circles, pythagorean-triples

Suppose we two equations $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ and 
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=2g^2$$

Where x,y and r are integer variables greater than 0. a,b and g are integer constants greater than 0.

I conjecture that for any given selection of a,b and g, the number of integer solutions of the form $(x,y,r)$ is less than or equal to 3. How would I go about proving or disproving this? Any tips on tackling this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi lulu. The radius r is a variable. So the first equation is actually giving an infinite set of circles that intersect with the circle in the second equation.

Comment: Thanks!  I worked that out and then removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get circles with more than $3$ such points...

**First**, consider "generating" circle of the form 
$$
x_0^2+y_0^2=2g^2,
$$
that has many integer points.
One of such rather small and "reach on integer points" circles is the circle with $g=1105=5\times 13\times 17$. It has $108$ integer points (for example).

**Second**, shift this circle at (any random) integer vector $(a,b)$ and check how many its integer points match condition
$$x^2+y^2=r^2,$$
where $r$ is integer.

**Then** for considered circle and for $(a,b)=(10, 1855)$ (for example) one will get system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
(x-10)^2+(y-1855)^2=2\cdot 1105^2,\\
x^2+y^2=r^2,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which has $4$ such $(x,y,r)$-solutions:

 $(x,y,r)=(231,308,385)$,

 $(x,y,r)=(377,336,505)$,

 $(x,y,r)=(1557,2076,2595)$,

 $(x,y,r)=(605,3300,3355)$.

And I believe that there are examples with more than $4$ points.

---

Ooops...
Consider the same $g=1105$, and $(a,b)=(73,1561)$.

 This construction gives us $7$ solutions:

$(x,y,r)=(440,42,442)$,

$(x,y,r)=(882,224,910)$,

$(x,y,r)=(1410,752,1598)$,

$(x,y,r)=(1592,1194,1990)$,

$(x,y,r)=(1634,1488,2210)$,

$(x,y,r)=(1224,2618,2890)$,

$(x,y,r)=(1130,2712,2938)$.

---

**Update:**

for $g=32045=5\times 13\times 17\times 29$ (circle with $324$ integer points)
 one can find $(a,b)=(823,45311)$, which give us $15$ solutions:

$(x,y,r)=(12720,  1582, 12818)$,

$(x,y,r)=(25382,  7224, 26390)$,

$(x,y,r)=(32144, 12558, 34510)$,

$(x,y,r)=(33576, 13990, 36374)$,

$(x,y,r)=(38910, 20752, 44098)$,

$(x,y,r)=(44552, 33414, 55690)$,

$(x,y,r)=(46134, 44488, 64090)$,

$(x,y,r)=(46040, 48342, 66758)$,

$(x,y,r)=(45080, 55062, 71162)$,

$(x,y,r)=(40062, 67984, 78910)$,

$(x,y,r)=(35064, 74998, 82790)$,

$(x,y,r)=(30510, 79552, 85202)$,

$(x,y,r)=(23496, 84550, 87754)$,

$(x,y,r)=(10574, 89568, 90190)$,

$(x,y,r)=( 3854, 90528, 90610)$.

Comment: Thanks! How did you find a 'g' with many integer points?

Comment: One can find such small $g$ via brute force (loops on $g$ and checking appropriate $x,y$). But this is closely related to **Gaussian Integers**. That's why decomposition of $1105$ has all prime numbers of the form $p=4k+1$ ($5=4\times 1+1$, $13=4\times 3+1$, $17=4\times 4+1$).

Comment: Can you find such $(a,b)$ for this $g=1105$, that give $8$ integer solutions? I am sure that such $(a,b)$ exist ;) .

Comment: @Ameet, I updated my answer with $(g,a,b)$ that generates $15$ solutions $(x,y,r)$.

Comment: Thanks Oleg567. Really appreciate it! Looks like my conjecture was way off. :) I will write my own program to generate these.

Comment: @Ameet, but this observation is good starting point for further interesting researches, and (perhaps) even small discoveries ;).